Edit/Change Name in SHELL display path
When I open my PowerShell in Windows 11, the PWD displayed is currently PS C:\Users\floro>
This comes from the Windows ID , the normal windows installation and configuration; After that i created a new user and delete the Microsoft linked Account.
Now the user is cabinet\secretariat (result of whoami) after joining the local domain.
But somehow, the ancient name rested and I don't know how to change it.
I want to display the shell like PS C:\Users\Secretariat
I tried to see if I can modify the registry, the name of the user, the local policy, but I didn't find a proper answer. Thanks.

Did you log in as the new user? If PS is still showing "floro", that is the name of the folder you are in. If you just changed the username, the user's folder is still going to be "floro". I don't think your problem is in PowerShell, but that you made some changes you THOUGHT would do something, but don't actually do what you want. Please clarify your question as much as you are able. Do your best to explain precisely what you have done, what you expect to happen, and what actually happened. Add this info to the question using the EDIT button.
